# "Resposta" que levam a resposta, mas não é a resposta, o que fazer?

Tags: suporte, perguntas, respostas

Em "How do I write a good answer?", existe o seguinte trecho:

> Leia a pergunta atentamente. O que, especificamente, está sendo
>   perguntado? Certifique-se de que sua resposta fornece essa informação
>   ou uma alternativa viável. A resposta pode ser “não faça isso”, mas
>   também deve incluir “tente isto como alternativa”. Qualquer resposta
>   que leve o interessado na direção correta é útil, mas tente mencionar
>   toda limitação, suposição ou simplificação em sua resposta. Ser breve
>   é aceitável, mas explicações mais completas são melhores.

Em especial "... Qualquer resposta que leve o interessado na direção correta é útil ...", este trecho ao meu ver significa que você pode responder uma parte da pergunta ou algo que leve a resposta, como por exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Me deparei com esta resposta na área de "Publicações de baixa qualidade", muitas vezes eu fico com dúvida nesta área, já que, respostas como esta não responde a pergunta, mas da direcionamento, em alguns casos a pessoa que fez a pergunta não sabe que existe este debug, como no exemplo acima, isso é útil para encontrar a resposta, mas não é a resposta.

Mas o que eu vejo na comunidade é uma postura diferente, "respostas" como estas são aceitas somente na área de comentários, mas como resposta não são aceitas, como me porta diante de respostas como esta, marca para exclusão, negativar ou deixar ativa?

Ou esta parte do "How do I write a good answer?" deve ser alterado, já que a comunidade não esta funciona desta forma, ou eu que estou interpretando esta parte de forma incorreta no texto?

Porque eu acho bom que exista resposta desta forma, porque na área de comentários muitas vezes não da para colocar de forma completa este direcionamento para a resposta.

Comment: Eu tenho um exemplo disso. No caso, estava um tanto quanto sem paciência e resolvi que o AP tivesse o trabalho para traduzir o meu pseudocódigo para VisualG: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/240531/64969; claro, tentei ser didático onde deveria, mas não quis que a pessoa copiasse e colasse o meu código, então foi uma estratégia de "ensino" que eu apliquei. E pavio curto no dia também...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A resposta do EMBarbosa parece correta e penso o mesmo.

Se não é uma resposta sinalize como "Não é uma resposta". Se é um comentário um moderador a converterá. Se nem pra isso servir será removido.

Pra mim o exemplo citado é um comentário porque nem se sabe se é aquilo que a pessoa quer. Claro que se houver algum esclarecimento e do contexto pode ser até que acabe se conformando como uma resposta aceitável, provavelmente não muito boa, mas que resolve, ainda que eu editaria para tirar a parte que deixa em dúvida se é aquilo.

É assim que eu faço. Quando eu tenho quase certeza que sei o que a pessoa perguntou, mas tem uma ligeira duvida eu respondo mostrando que pode não ser bem aquilo. Se a pessoa demonstra que é mesmo eu edito para deixar como certeza, se ela esclarece eu melhoro a resposta, se não consigo melhorar a resposta eu apago (mas nem todo mundo faz, então não sei se pode dar o mesmo tratamento para todo mundo, é preço de ser novo ou não participar ativamente de uma comunidade), se ela diz que é outro coisa totalmente diferente do que está na pergunta, eu costumo fechar a pergunta por não estar clara. EM alguns casos é salvável.

Se um comentário não tem espaço suficiente faça em mais que um, coloque um *link* para algo externo, diminua o texto. Ser longo não é justificativa para postar um comentário como se fosse resposta.

Ser breve é diferente de não ser uma resposta. Pode dar um resposta boa em 30 caracteres, e fazer um comentário em 30 mil e ainda não ser uma resposta.

Eu sei que muitas vezes é difícil perceber se é uma resposta ou não. Eu pulo várias sinalizações que eu não sei dizer ao certo se é ou não é. Não domino todos os assuntos.

Answer (score 5):

Acho que você deve considerar o **contexto** desta frase.
Note o que está escrito antes:

> A resposta pode ser “não faça isso”, mas também deve incluir “tente
>   isto como alternativa”.

E depois:

> mas tente mencionar toda limitação, suposição
>   ou simplificação em sua resposta. Ser breve é aceitável, mas
>   explicações mais completas são melhores.

Veja que essas duas partes estão falando de certas limitações de uma **resposta**. Quer dizer, as vezes não é possível fazer exatamente o que a pessoa quer, mas é possível ter uma alternativa. 
Nestes casos, ou situações similares, a frase *"Qualquer resposta que leve o interessado na direção correta é útil"* então incentiva a postar algo que **seja uma resposta**, mesmo que não seja exatamente o que o autor quer.

Por outro lado, se uma pergunta não está clara o suficiente, deve-se buscar as informações necessárias para responder. E isso é feito nos comentários, como você disse.